# mySQL adding rows to an auto_increment column

Tags: mysql

I have looked around for this answer but have found it nowhere. I have a table with one column that is set to auto increment. I know that if I add other columns and more values that it will increment accordingly, however, is there a way to insert rows from say 1 through 10 (sort of like a loop) into the column without other columns?

Thanks!

P.S Newbie in mySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert the values into that one column:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
```